# How do I execute a function passed as props between components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in troubble. When I was creating the logout function using **React**, a problem occurred.

My **"Auth"** component send info in state and function to **"AuthMenu"** component.

But, the logout function in this code, `<Btn onClick={logout}>Logout</Btn>`, is not working.

When I checked the props in **"AuthMenu"**, `console.log(logout);` showed the function's code well. But, not working..

Am I writing the wrong code?

.

`Auth.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { GetUser } from '../../controllers/auth'

class Auth extends Component {
    state = {
        info: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            img: '/icons/user.png',
        },
    }

    handleSetAuth(data) {
        this.setState({
            info: {
                id: data.user_id,
                name: data.user_nickname,
                img: '/icons/user.png', 
            }
        });
    }

    handleDeleteAuth() {
        console.log("Logout Successful!");
        this.setState({
            info: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                img: '/icons/user.png',
            }
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('tk') !== null){
            GetUser((data)=> {
                if (this.state.info !== data)
                this.handleSetAuth(data);
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <AuthMenu info={this.state.info} logout={this.handleDeleteAuth}></AuthMenu>
        );
    }
}

export default Auth
```

`AuthMenu.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

...

const Btn = styled.button`
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .2s ${transition};
    ${noselect}

    &:hover,
    &:active {
        background-color: ${palette.gray8};
        color: white;
    }

    ${media.small} {
        width: 80px;
    }
`;

...

const AuthMenu = ({info, logout})=> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('tk');
    if (token === null) {
        return (
          <Container>
            <IconImg src={info.img} alt="User" />
            <ContentWrap>
              <Btn>Login</Btn>
            </ContentWrap>
          </Container>
        )
    } else {
        return (
          <Container>
            <IconImg src={info.img} alt="User" />
            <ContentWrap>
              <Name>{info.name}</Name>
              <Btn onClick={logout}>Logout</Btn>
            </ContentWrap>
          </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default AuthMenu
```

Comment: This Error is solved. 
I wrote the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your onClick working properly, just ignoring the prop, sometimes clicks don't work on certain components, you can try this

```
              <Btn onClick={() => {console.log("clicked");
logout()}}>Logout</Btn>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I change the code using your solution, but still not working..

I don't know solution for this problem...

```
<Btn onClick={()=> {
         console.log("clicked!");
         logout()
        }}>Logout</Btn>
```
`console.log("clicked");` is not working..

Comment: Did you get "clicked" in console, this was not the solution but a check. In case not, you have to post the code for Btn because problem is then not your callback but onClick not working

Comment: I think the Btn is just styled-component. Is this the cause of the unwanted action? I added code under.

Comment: no its fine....i see another Btn there now, is that getting rendered which is not having any onClick or the logout one

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! Probably I will delete the code and rewrite it. 

Answer (score 0):

your `handleDeleteAuth` is not binded to the component.
please add `logout={this.handleDeleteAuth.bind(this}` or change it to be arrow function:

```
    const handleDeleteAuth = () => {
        console.log("Logout Successful!");
        this.setState({
            info: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                img: '/icons/user.png',
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I change the code, thanks to you! But, Logout function is still not working..

Answer (score 0):

In my code,  is just styled-component.

Is this the cause of the unwanted action?

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Btn = styled.button`
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .2s ${transition};
    ${noselect}

    &:hover,
    &:active {
        background-color: ${palette.gray8};
        color: white;
    }

    ${media.small} {
        width: 80px;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved!

The cause of error is `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`.

Bug's Scenario is that.

1. Click Logout Button. (Logout Buttton is included by Memu component)
2. Executed event of Menu compoennt. (Menu component is modal included by body.)
3. stoped event propagation.
4. Logout button can not work.

I have had this error for over 6 hours.This is just my mistake!!!